# Unsupported API version when using 'Tone analyzer'

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, tone-analyzer

Using 2020 version of IBM Cloud

[image: Error Messages from Debug Window]

[image: Update on Error Message from Debug Window]

It is very confusing that although I created my Tone Analyzer service with my Lite account, and I entered the correct API Key and URL from the credentials into the Tone Analyzer v3 node, I still cannot get my correct output. Why would it say my URL is unsupported when that link is all they gave me?

Also, the URL https://api.us-south.tone-analyzer.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/dc514b3e-bf2f-478c-98f8-3734568eb05c returns this line of code:

```
{"code":401,"error":"Unauthorized","trace":"7285079c-db8b-40b3-9422-0832b5857e52"}
```

Is this something to really give a look at? I checked this post [Can't access IBM Tone Analyzer API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912989/cant-access-ibm-tone-analyzer-api) but am quite unsure of where and how to edit this code to make it useful.

---

**Solution That Works:** @data_henrik 's answer.
Also, if this happen to be your case too, set version_date to 'Dominant Tone', as shown below.
[image: Supplement to the answer]

Comment: What API version are you specifying in your request?

Comment: @nitind Mind telling me how to check it? From the previous posts, I could see the version just from their URLs, but I can't tell from mine. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the API documentation for the [Tone Analyzer on versioning](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/tone-analyzer#versioning). The API requires to set a **version=yyyy-mm-dd** parameter. The latest (most recent) is **version=2017-09-21**.

Comment: Could I ask you to elaborate on how to set the version? Is it to paste 'version=2017-09-21' into the description of the Tone Analyzer node?